# Overriding labels on Django formfields/models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to edit the labels for the Form Field as displayed on my webpage. I have followed the same format as in the Django documentation, as seen in the following link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields. However, my labels remain unchanged. I am using Django 1.6.5, so it should definitely support the labels override. Any ideas?

My code is as follows:

```
#forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm, RadioSelect
from webpage.models import Career
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class ApplyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Career
        fields=['name','email','phone','position_desired','street_address','city','state','zip_code','high_school','hsloc','hssub','hsyears','hsgrad']
        widgets = {
            'hsgrad': RadioSelect,
        }
        labels = {
            'hsloc': _('Location: '),
            'hssub': _('Subject(s) Studied/Degree(s) Received: '),
            'hsyears': _('Years Completed: '),
            'hsgrad': _('Did you graduate? '),
        }

#models.py
from django.db import models
from localflavor.us.models import PhoneNumberField, USStateField, ZipCodeField

BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))

# Create your models here.
class Career(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    phone=PhoneNumberField()
    position_desired=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    street_address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state=USStateField()
    zip_code=ZipCodeField()

    high_school = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hsloc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hssub = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hsyears = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    hsgrad = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES, blank=False, default='Unspecified')
```

Comment: Why don't you declare the labels directly inside your model (makes the model more readable:
`hsloc = models.CharField(_('Location'),max_length=50)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should definetely ignore them:

From Django Documentation:

> ModelForm is a regular Form which can automatically generate certain fields. The fields that are automatically generated depend on the content of the Meta class and on which fields have already been defined declaratively. **Basically, ModelForm will only generate fields that are missing from the form, or in other words, fields that weren’t defined declaratively**.
>
> Fields defined declaratively are left as-is, **therefore any
> customizations made to Meta attributes such as widgets, labels,
> help_texts, or error_messages are ignored; these only apply to fields
> that are generated automatically.**

Declare your labels directly in the model:

```
class Career(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    phone=PhoneNumberField()
    position_desired=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    street_address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state=USStateField()
    zip_code=ZipCodeField()

    high_school = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hsloc = models.CharField(_('Location'),max_length=50)
    hssub = models.CharField(_('Subject(s) Studied/Degree(s) Received'),max_length=50)
    hsyears = models.CharField(_('Years Completed'),max_length=10)
    hsgrad = models.BooleanField(_('Did you graduate?'),choices=BOOL_CHOICES, blank=False, default='Unspecified')
```

Comment: What are you talking about? please read before posting this kind of answers or downvoting answers.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names

Comment: And what are YOU talking about? Verbose names are NOT labels. Just because form uses the verbose name if a label is missing doesn't mean that they're the same thing. This discussion is ridiculous.

Comment: Can you please understand DRY? what would be re-declare the fields in the Form when the verbose_name is what Django uses to render form labels in the first time? is there a need to define 2 separate labels? or would max_length of a Model Form be different from the max_length of a Model? We are talking for already existing Model fields, NOT additional fields that need to be used only by the form.

Comment: Read about `Separation of concerns`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'm a bit confused as to what the difference in the Django documentation example that I linked to is though. They were able to declare the labels on the form page like I had coded previously for the name attribute of an Author Model.

Comment: Mate you have a thing, there is no separation of Concerns when we are talking about Model Forms, I am not talking about simple forms, don't bring Martin Fowler on the desk it is totally unrelated to how Django uses ModelForms, ModelForms are used for DRY, using the Model attributes and no needing to redefine the entire Model class again.

Comment: @user3876837 the difference is how ModelForm works, ModelForm is actually a helper class, constructing a Form for Model, so it uses the build in Model Fields to create the Form Fields that it's going to use.
Since you are declaring the fields attribute, its essentially like telling to the ModelForm that you want to use the Fields of the Model, in turn attributes of Model are respected as Form Field attributes, unless you generate fields manually in the ModelForm (as AshishKasturia mentioned, something though YOU DON'T need to as ModelForm handles.